# Can we use any compiler for SASS files in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a SASS project in SharePoint but I didn't have any idea how to use a compiler for SASS files as I need to change in SASS files for customization. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For compile SAAS you can use [Scout App](http://scout-app.io/). Just add your style project and click start. It'll regenerate css anytime, when you change files.

How to work with CSS in sharepoint look official [recommendations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/css-recommendations).

Hope it'll help you.